# Entity Framework T4 template and TFS

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, tfs

Today I discovered that TFS does not handle T4 generated classes well. I updated my Entity Framework **edmx** which triggers the T4 template to run. The template deletes and re-writes all of the `.cs` files. Then it seems TFS cannot keep up and thinks they're all deleted.

When I view the Pending Changes and try to undo, TFS complains saying that the files still exist and if I want to undo, I need to delete the local files first.

I had thought we could perhaps just exclude the generated files from TFS but I'm not sure if that will work in automated build environments.

I also found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/07/considerations-when-managing-source-control-via-visual-studio-team-foundation-server-and-using-text-template-transformation-toolkit-to-generate-net4-entity-framework-objects.aspx) but the solutions given still seem pretty tedious.

Is there a better solution around this?

Comment: That article is more of a management issue, than the same problem you are having. I take it you are using "Local Workspaces" in TFS 2012? I use T4 and TFS everyday and never see this problem.

Comment: This is probably being caused by the fact that once you have a pending delete, you can't do an add in TFS. You should either commit the delete first, or undo it and then do the add. So deleting all and then overwriting is a recipe for disaster... You could delete and commit, then regenerate all the t4's...

Comment: @DaveShaw re: Local Workspace - I guess so. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I randomly but infrequently see this issue as well. It is a real PITA and I don't think the above comments are relevant. Most of the time after "update model from database" this is not a problem. Sometimes it is. I have never been able to figure out what causes this and one has to manually delete all the files still there so you can then undo the changes. Would love to find a solution or at least the cause. Oddly another EF bug is where every rebuild after any change, always marks the first generated object as changed but it never changes.